# Find the minimum risk location equivariant estimator of $\theta$ with $P(X_j = \theta) = P(X_j = θ + 1) =1/2$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

Following this question:[Why the Pitman estimator is given by the sample mean of X and Y?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/620730/why-the-pitman-estimator-is-given-by-the-sample-mean-of-x-and-y).

Let $X_1, \dots ,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables having distribution
$P(X_j = \theta) = P(X_j = θ + 1) =1/2,$
where $\theta\in Z$ is an integer valued unknown location parameter. Find the minimum
risk location equivariant estimator of $\theta$ for the squared error loss function.

---

It seems that the answer is the median of $\{X_1,\dots, X_n\}$. I try to get the posterior distribution of $\theta$ but I cannot do that. The likelihood function
$$
L(\theta, X)=\prod_{i=1}^n p(X_i|\theta)=?
$$

It seems that the posterior distribution is also maximized when $\theta$ is equal to the most common value among the $X_i$. Therefore, the minimum risk location equivariant estimator is $\hat{\theta}=mode\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$.

Comment: Note that you are supposed to find the MRLE estimator for the squared error loss function, not the maximum a posteriori estimator.

Comment: @jbowman Thanks. So what do I need to do?